# Using Aliases to Run Shell Script OSX

Tags: unix, terminal, npm

Terminal noob, but I am a web developer. I saw that with AlfredApp Powerpack you could create workflows and execute shell scripts and what not. I think I can do it from the command line.

I went into my .bash_profile and added an alias.
My ultimate goal:
cd into a blank directory
run "alias project_boilerplate"
That alias:
a - Runs the scripts itself or
b - opens a exactable file

I created the exactable file and did the chmod. This file will clone a git repo. npm install gulp. And then npm install a bunch of other dependancies.

So simply, how would I make this alias, then execute a file (that I have made).

Answer (score 0):

You can define an alias like this:

```
alias ff='cd /tmp; ls -al'
```

Then you can just use the ff command.
If you save the definition in your profile it will always be added when you login.
I just used the ls command to illustrate running a program after changing directory.
The ; separates the two commands as though you entered a carriage return.